# IEnumerator yield return type error

Tags: unity-game-engine, return-value, ienumerator

i have found similar questions, but I was not able to solve my problem with the provided answers.

I have the following code, that is supposed to fade between colors in an array.

```
public static IEnumerator FadeMaterialColors(Material m, Color[] colors, float speed, ProgressCurve type){
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++){
        yield return (FadeMaterialColorTo(m, colors[i%2], speed, type));
    }
    yield return null;
}

public static IEnumerator FadeMaterialColorTo(Material m, Color target, float duration, ProgressCurve type){
        Color start = m.color;
        float y, t = Time.time;
        float progress = (Time.time - t)/duration;

        while (progress < 1f){
            y = GetProgressCurve(progress, type);
            m.color = start + y*(target - start);
            yield return null; // return here next frame
            progress = (Time.time - t)/duration;
        }
        m.color = target;
    }
```

The function "FadeMaterialColorTo" itself is working fine, but i see no results when calling it with the top function... I have tried dropping the yield in line 3 to get"return (FadeMaterialColorTo(m, colors[i%2], speed, type));" but then i get the following error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.IEnumerator' to `bool'
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603154/ienumeratort-implementation) is a similar topic, but in Unity a return type IEnumerator> does not work

```
The non-generic type `System.Collections.IEnumerator' cannot be used with the type arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want is something like:

```
public static IEnumerator FadeMaterialColors(Material m, Color[] colors, float speed,
ProgressCurve type){
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++){
        yield return StartCoroutine(FadeMaterialColorTo(m, colors[i%2], speed, type));
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

IIRC, something like `yield return somefunction()` will yield only once if you have another nested yield inside `somefunction()`, as you do with the `yield return null` in the body of your `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. StartCoroutine is not callable from a static Method. i found a workaround  [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=46803&d=1363320165) which was taken from [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/15524-Static-StartCoroutine)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative way:

```
public static IEnumerator FadeMaterialColors(Material m, Color[] colors, float speed, ProgressCurve type){
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++){
        IEnumerator process = FadeMaterialColorTo(m, colors[i%2], speed, type);
        while(process.MoveNext())
            yield return null;
    }
    yield return null;
}
```